# Groupby and apply multiple lambda functions to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
prod_cat_1    initial_inventory     prediction    delta_quantity
groceries           10                 12               5
medicines            4                 20               4
groceries           12                 12               5

(...)
```

And I would like to compute, for each category within "prod_cat_1" and with a single groupby:

```
lambda x: round((x.initial_inventory/x.prediction).mean(), 4) 
lambda x: round((x.delta_quantity/x.prediction).mean(), 4)
```

naming them, respectively, *inventory_threshold* and *delta_threshold*

example output would be:

```
prod_cat_1    inventory_threshold    delta_threshold    
medicines           0.2                     0.2        
groceries           0.91666                 0.416666
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this answered your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295172/how-to-use-multiple-lambda-function-for-a-pandas-groupby

Comment: It is indeed the right answer! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

(Updated answer to get the same results)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'prod_cat_1': ['groceries', 'medecine', 'groceries'],
    'initial_inventory': [10,4,12],
    'prediction': [12,20,12],
    'delta_quantities': [5,4,5]
})

df.groupby('prod_cat_1').apply(lambda x: x.mean()/x['prediction'].mean()).drop('prediction',axis=1).round(4)
```

gives:

```
    initial_inventory   delta_quantities
prod_cat_1      
groceries   0.9167  0.4167
medecine    0.2000  0.2000
```

Comment: Is there a chance to apply a single "agg" or "apply" within the initial groupby?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli yes, check my answer

Comment: Don't think it's 100% what I'm looking for; each lambda should create a new feature (hence, 2 in total)

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli I'm not sure I follow what you want. Would you mind providing a sample output

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli check the updated answer, it should do what you need